# Find the Set of All Accumulation Points (also called Limit Points) for the given set S.

Tags: real-analysis

***Find the Set of All Accumulation Points (also called Limit Points) for the given set $S$.***

$S = \{a_n:n\in \Bbb{N}\}$ where $a_n = \left\{ \begin{array}{c} 0\text{, if } n \text{ is odd} \\ \dfrac{n}{n+1}\text{, if } n \text{ is even} \end{array} \right..$

In my perspective there are two possible answers.

1) $L(S) = \{0,1\}$

Using the definition of the accumulation or limit point, of a sequence. The number $a$ is said to be an accumulation point of $(a_n)$ if there exists a subsequence such that the limit of the subsequence is equal to $a$.

2) $L(S) = \{1\}$

Using the definition of the accumulation or limit point of a set.

The point $a$ is an accumulation point of the set $S$ if each neighborhood of $a$ contains a point of $S$, other than $a$.

$1$ is the only accumulation point because not all the neighborhoods of $0$ contain a point of the set $S$ other than $0$.

As the question mentions ***"the given set $S$"***, I vote for the second answer.

***What do you think?***

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Thank you for your comment! What do you think about the second answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical question is whether $S$ is a set or a sequence.  You call it a set, but defining values for $a_n$ for all $n$ makes it sound like a sequence.  If it is a set, it can have only one member $0$.  If it is a sequence, all the odd positions are $0$.  As a sequence, it has an accumulation point at $0$ and an accumulation point at $1$ because you can select a subsequence converging to each of those two points.  It does not have a limit because there are members of the sequence with arbitrarily high indices that are far from $0$ and others that are far from $1$.  As a set, the only accumulation point is $1$.  Sets are not considered to have limits because they lack the concept of order.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Just one correction to your proof. You wrote "You call it a set." I am not guilty! That is given in the problem.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam May you please explain your reasoning?

Comment: @AbdallahHammam limit point of a sequence or limit point of the set?

Comment: If we treat $S$ as a set, it is $\{0,2/3,4/5,6/7\ldots\}$ and it has only $1$ as an accumulation point.  If we treat it as a sequence, it is $(0,2/3,0,4/5,0,6/7\ldots)$ and it has both $0$ and $1$ as accumulation points.  As your problem says it is a set and uses braces, I would take that interpretation and say only $1$ qualifies, but I think it is important to understand the distinction.  That is why I gave both in my answer.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The set  $S$ will be like $ {0, 2/3, 4/5.....}$ And so around $0$ there is some neighborhood which contains only $0$. But for $1$, you cannot find such neighborhood. Hence the set has one limit point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, the definition says "if each neighborhood of a contains a point of S, other than a." That means ALL the neighborhoods, one neighborhood is not enough. As S is an infinite set, around 1 there exist infinite neighbordhoods containing 1.

Comment: Yes. That's the definition to be a limit point. So zero is not limit point. 1 is

Comment: You wrote the opposite, right?

Comment: Remember that if you can find a neighborhood around a point which doesn't have other points except itself, then that point can't be limit point.

Comment: Oh... you are right! I am so sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: The limit of a non stationary sequence is a limit point. only $1$ is a limit point.